# How do I move a Windows menu in MDI Windows Forms?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, mdi

I want to move the *Windows* menu item of an MDI Windows Forms to a toolbar. Basically, take the functionality and transfer it somewhere else. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Are you talking about the [ToolStrip Merge](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5523fet0(v=vs.110).aspx) method?  Otherwise, your question is sparse on details.

Comment: That looks like it. If I only want the menu item to be added to the toolstrip, is that possible? If not, how do I build it? I don't want the menu to be there anymore. Just the toolstrip.

Answer (score 2):

[`MenuStrip`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.menustrip(v=vs.110).aspx), [`ToolStrip`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstrip(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`ToolStripPanel`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstrippanel(v=vs.110).aspx) components provide built-in support for what you need:

- You can move items of `ToolStrip` or `MenuStrip` between different `ToolStrip` or `MenuStrip` components or reorder them. To do so, it's enough to have some `ToolStrip` and `MenuStrip` on your form and set `AllowItemReorder` of them to `true`. Then you can simply move items between strips by holding <kbd>Alt</kbd> key down and dragging the item and dropping it on target.
- You can also move a `ToolStrip` or `MennuStrip` to another side of form. To do so, you should use `ToolStripPanel` to host `ToolStrip`. Then you can move the strip by grabbing its grip and moving it to another `ToolStrip` Panel.

[image]

These are settings which will help you to create such UI:

- To be able to move toolstrip in your from, you should use `ToolStripPanel`. You can not use `ToolStripContainer` in Mdi Forms.
- `ToolStripPanel` is not present in toolbox by default and you should right click on toolbox and choose items and add it to the toolbox from list of .net components.
- `ToolStripPanel` is an auto-size component when it is docked. So first add `MenuStrip` and `ToolStrip` to it, then dock it to `Top`. Also add another one and dock it to `Bottom` without adding any toolstrip. We will use it to move toolstrip to bottom of form.
- For `ToolStrip` and `MenuStrip` set `AllowItemReorder` to `true` to be able to move them between different strips. To move item, hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> key down and drag the item and drop on target.
- Handle `ItemRemoved` event of `MenuStrip` and check if the `Items` collection is empty, then set visible of menu to `false`.

Comment: I've added the ToolStripPanel to the toolbox. I've set the MenuStrip.AllowItemReorder to true. I've dragged a ToolStripPanel onto the form. When I try to drag a menu item from the MenuStrip onto the TSP, I get a circle with a slash through it (even when holding down alt). Trying to Dock the TSP makes it basically disappear since it doesn't have a height. Any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: I missed the part about putting them into the TSP. I have that done and Docked but still can't add menu items to the toolbar.

Comment: Moving items between Strips doesn't need `ToolStripPanel`. So as a start point, without using `ToolStripPanel` just put a `MenuStrip` and a `ToolStrip` and set `AllowItemReorder` to `true` for both. Then holding Alt key down, drag a menu and drop it on `ToolStrip`.

Comment: `ToolStripPanel` is for moving the whole `ToolStrip`. If you want to move the `ToolStrip` to another side of your form, then you should use `ToolStripPanle`.

Comment: Just using cut/paste worked. No TSP needed. But, I noticed the menu strip item looses all of its functionality.  So if you move Windows from the menustrip to the toolstrip, it will no longer do anything. Any ideas on that?

Comment: The answer I posted is for run-time! At design-time you should use copy paste. At design-time, you only need a simple copy paste.

Comment: Doesn't fix the problem that the menu strip item looses all its functionality.